# Select max with group by on other table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `users_item` that has 2 columns `user_id, item_id` and `item_rates` that has 2 `columns rate_item_id, rate`.

They are connected with Foreign_Key on `users_item.item_id = item_rates.rate_item_id`. I need to
select item_id's with max rate for a given range of users. One user can have a lot of items.
My select is:

```
SELECT MAX(rate), rate_item_id, user_id 
FROM users_item JOIN item_rates ON item_id = rate_item_id  
AND user_id in (2706,2979) GROUP BY user_id;
```

but it returns not correspondent item_id's with max rate. In given example select has to return just 2 rows. Can someone help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what you want.. Try this:

```
SELECT users_item.user_id, item_id, maxrate
FROM user_items 
JOIN item_rates ON users_item.item_id = item_rates.rate_item_id
JOIN (SELECT MAX(rate) AS maxrate, user_id 
      FROM users_item JOIN item_rates ON item_id = rate_item_id
      WHERE user_id in (1,2)
      GROUP BY user_id) AS maxis
ON users_item.USER_ID = maxis.USER_ID
WHERE item_rates.rate = maxrate
```

The reason you need a subquery is that ***multiple different items own by the same user could have the same rate and this could be the maximum rate*** of user's owned items.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by `user_id, rate_item_id`

I'm surprised that MySql doesn't give you an error, Oracle would...

Comment: In MySQL it depends on server setting `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` - without that set MySQL will not complain (but you will get a "random" value for the columns that are not part of the grouping). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: It doesn't help. Returns 14 rows instead of 2 I need.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic : SQLfiddle seems to have some iusses today... even stupid DDL are rejected with `Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.: `